# avoid race condition by making tasks depend on a nontask object

Tags: java

This question comes from section sharing resources of Think in java.

> Note that in this example the class that can be canceled is not Runnable. Instead, all the EvenChecker tasks that depend on the IntGenerator object test it to see whether it’s been canceled, as you can see in run( ).

And

> For example, a task cannot depend on another task, because task
>   shutdown order is not guaranteed. **Here, by making tasks depend on a
>   nontask object, we eliminate the potential race condition**.

How to understand it?

```
public abstract class IntGenerator {
  private volatile boolean canceled = false;
  public abstract int next();
  public void cancel() { canceled = true; }
  public boolean isCanceled() { return canceled; }
}

public class EvenChecker implements Runnable {
  private IntGenerator generator;
  private final int id;
  public EvenChecker(IntGenerator g, int ident) {
    generator = g;
    id = ident;
  }
  public void run() {
    while(!generator.isCanceled()) {
      int val = generator.next();
      if(val % 2 != 0) {
        System.out.println(val + " not even!");
        generator.cancel(); 
      }
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: The explanation is very unclear - I'd suggest to find a better book if you are interested in concurrency. (I would also note that in 99% of situations, there is no good reason to have a boolean flag to cancel tasks - Java provides a native interruption mechanism).

Answer (score 1):

A race condition occurs when two or more tasks start parallel and, depending on which task comes first, cause your program to react differently, inexpectedly or even crash. Without appropriate precautions (ExecutorService, for example) you can't control the order entirely as the underlying operating system always is the last to decide then.

For example. Your have an

```
ArrayList<String> listA
```

and you have 3 independed Runnables.

- Runnable A is supposed to add 20 Strings to that list.
- Runnable B has to put them all to lower case.
- Runnable C drops duplicates.

Starting them parallel would cause chaos.

Maybe the wanted order is given. Then the expected result will be a list with no duplicates and all Strings have lower case.

But what if Runnable C comes first and even B is faster than A?

Then your listA would neither be free from duplicates nor would your Strings be brought to lower case.

This is what race condition is generally about. (put in simple words)

So back to your example.

Would IntGenerator be a Runnable too, you'd surely have a lot of trouble to harmonize both Runnables to interact properly with each other. I wouldn't go that far to say that it is impossible, but troublesome.